# Can I use an Arduino for controlling MOSFET transistors to make a pure sine wave AC power inverter?

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, ac, dc, inverter

Modern AC invertors use controllers to turn on/off transistors to generate PWM pulses that will become a pure sine after filtering.

Is it possible to use an Arduino as that controller? What cheap microcontroller can be used if not?

I'm making that invertor just for fun (for learning), not for selling.

P.S. Yes, I know about high voltage danger. I will be OK with 12 V, 50 Hz AC.

Comment: Certainly. It is just another microcontroller, and it's not like the Arduino has to deal with the high voltage itself. For a circuit where precise timing is important, you might want to find out how to disable interrupts.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to drive a H-bridge then you need either 2 or 4 PWM signals. Two if dead time is handled by the MOSFET drivers, four if the micro handles dead time. So you need a micro with this number of PWMs that can be synchronized accurately, so they should run from the same timer-counter unit.

A useful feature is also a hardware comparator, or at least an input that stops all PWM and sets everything to off, in order to implement fast short circuit and overcurrent protection. Then you can use a current sense amp, or a Hall sensor, compare its output to a maximum current threshold, and have it cut off the drive to the MOSFETs if it goes over the limit.

This can be done in software, but it will be much slower. Hardware protection can be fast enough to save MOSFETs from a direct short, with software, probably not. Also software has bugs and sometimes you use the debugger and that pauses code execution. A hardware protection will work no matter what, even better it will prevent the software bugs from exploding the MOSFETs.

If you like AVR, I know AT90PWM3B offers this feature, I don't know if the arduino micro does.

If you want a nice cheap MOSFET driver for 12V, check out [ADP3120](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/adp3120a-d.pdf) from OnSemi, also other references in the same family, costs about 50c and works well.